# Laravel 5.2 - Eloquent Model Query

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm having trouble trying to perform a really basic query using an Eloquent Model, where *create* and *find* both work fine but *where* returns nothing.

**Model:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
protected $table = 'companies';
protected $fillable = ['name', 'ticker', 'industry', 'sector', 'description'];
protected $visible = ['name', 'ticker', 'industry', 'sector', 'description'];
}
```

**Controller:**

*Create* works fine:

```
\App\Company::create(['ticker'=>'AAPL', 'name' => 'Apple Inc']);
```

creates a new row on the DB:

> (id, name, ticker)
>
> 1, Apple Inc, AAPL

*Find* works fine:

```
$company = \App\Company::find(1);
print_r($company);
```

returns

> App\Company Object ( [table:protected] => companies [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => ticker [2] => industry [3] => sector [4] => description ) [visible:protected] => Array ( [0] => name [1] => ticker [2] => industry [3] => sector [4] => description ) [connection:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Apple Inc [ticker] => AAPL [industry] => [sector] => [description] => [created_at] => 2016-01-14 00:01:35 [updated_at] => 2016-01-14 00:01:35 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Apple Inc [ticker] => AAPL [industry] => [sector] => [description] => [created_at] => 2016-01-14 00:01:35 [updated_at] => 2016-01-14 00:01:35 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 [wasRecentlyCreated] => )

---

Now when I try to search by any field other than the id it simply doesn't return anything:

```
$company = \DB::table('companies')->select('ticker', 'name')->where('ticker', '=', 'AAPL')->get();
print_r($company);
```

returns an empty array:

> Array ( )

And both:

```
$company = \App\Company::find(['ticker', 'AAPL'])->first();
print_r($company);
```

and:

```
$company = \App\Company::where('ticker', '=', 'AAPL')->first();
print_r($company);
```

they simply return nothing at all.

---Update---

**Migration:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration
{   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('ticker');
            $table->string('industry')->nullable();
            $table->string('sector')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('companies');
    }
}
```

Comment: $company = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE ticker = :tickervar"), array('tickervar' => 'AAPL',)); doesn't work neither... it returns an empty array

Comment: What does your `migration` look like for this table? Is `id` a PK? I figure so but trying to think outside the box. Odd that it doesn't work.

Comment: Just updated with the migration... Funny thing is that it works when searching by name: $ticker = \App\Company::where('name', '=', 'Apple Inc')->first();... Could it be because of the ->unique()? But then again first() would make no sense at all.. there would always be just one.

Comment: Suggestion: dump out the results of `App\Company::where('ticker', '=', 'AAPL')->toSql();` or install https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to see what the query is, then run that query against your database directly.

Comment: @ceejayoz that shows that 'AAPL' is missing! But how could that be?! dump: select * from `companies` where `ticker` = ?

Comment: @JuanSerrats It's not missing, `toSql` shows the parameterized query. The debugbar will show the filled-in version.

Comment: You can see the value that's being passed to the `?` by doing `App\Company::where('ticker', '=', 'AAPL')->getBindings();`

Comment: The binding seems to be fine: Array ( [0] => AAPL )

Comment: Ok, I just updated the ticker manually on the DB (basically from "AAPL" to "AAPL"... same thing) but it did the trick and it's now working. I trim the ticker before creating the record.. and I grab and store the name and ticker in the same fashion and at the same time. This sounds impossible, but could the caps have anything to do?

Comment: @JuanSerrats Caps shouldn't make a difference, but if you copied AAPL from a webpage sometimes there are little weird characters that get copied over. Zero-length spaces etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $tick); did the trick. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:**

The tickers I was reading from other websites came with weird charactes (credit goest to @ceejayoz, thanks for your help)

Creating a `Company` manually worked fine because I was 'hard coding' the ticker:

```
\App\Company::create(['ticker'=>'AAPL', 'name' => 'Apple Inc']);
```

As for the companies I was scrapping from other sites, doing this before storing did the trick:

```
str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $ticker);
```

Obviously if the ticker had a carry and/or zero-length spaces and I was querying using a trimmed ticker the results where empty. Once updated the tickers the `Model` works fine for:

```
$company = \App\Company::where('ticker', '=', $ticker)->first();
```